# How do I implement a like button function to posts in Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am trying to add a like button feature to my code that allows users to like specific posts. The likes will be linked to a logged in user and the number of likes will be shown. Implementing the front end won't be difficult but I am having a problem with the back end.

I am [using this post here as a guide which does a follower system instead](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers)

This is what I have so far?

I have created a table for likes in models.py :

```
likers = db.Table('likers',
    db.Column('liker_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id')),
    db.Column('liked_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
)
```

In my Models.py for my user class:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
#Code 
liked = db.relationship(
    'User', secondary=likers,
    primaryjoin=(likers.c.liker_id == id),
    secondaryjoin=(likers.c.liked_id == id),
    backref = db.backref('likers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
def like(self, post):
    if not self.is_liking(post):
        self.liked.append(post)

def unlike(self, post):
    if self.is_liking(post):
        self.liked.remove(post)

def is_liking(self, post):
    return self.liked.filter(
        likers.c.liked_id == post.id).count() > 0
```

In my routes.py for my users blueprint I have:

```
@users.route("/like/<int:post_id>")
@login_required
def like(post_id):
 post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
 current_user.like(post)
 db.session.commit()
 flash('Post has been liked')
 return redirect(url_for('posts.post', post_id=post.id))

@users.route("/unlike/<int:post_id>")
@login_required
def unlike(post_id):
 post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
 current_user.unlike(post)
 db.session.commit()
 flash('Post has been unliked')
 return redirect(url_for('posts.post', post_id=post.id))
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting errors such as:

```
builtins.KeyError
KeyError: 'likers'
```

I have done a comment section and I know the relationship for the likes will be similar to the comments but I am struggling to implement it. I am relatively new to flask and I have tried using the documentations but haven't found anything to help me...

This is my final hope.

Comment: On your 'likers' table your foreign key for liker_id should refer to user.id, not post.id. Posts don't like posts, users like posts.

Comment: @onosendi i have done this but i am still getting problems

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    # Code
    liked = db.relationship(
        'PostLike',
        foreign_keys='PostLike.user_id',
        backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def like_post(self, post):
        if not self.has_liked_post(post):
            like = PostLike(user_id=self.id, post_id=post.id)
            db.session.add(like)

    def unlike_post(self, post):
        if self.has_liked_post(post):
            PostLike.query.filter_by(
                user_id=self.id,
                post_id=post.id).delete()

    def has_liked_post(self, post):
        return PostLike.query.filter(
            PostLike.user_id == self.id,
            PostLike.post_id == post.id).count() > 0


class PostLike(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post_like'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))


@app.route('/like/<int:post_id>/<action>')
@login_required
def like_action(post_id, action):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first_or_404()
    if action == 'like':
        current_user.like_post(post)
        db.session.commit()
    if action == 'unlike':
        current_user.unlike_post(post)
        db.session.commit()
    return redirect(request.referrer)
```

Then when you're listing your posts, set your anchors something like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if current_user.has_liked_post(post) %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('like_action', post_id=post.id, action='unlike') }}">Unlike</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('like_action', post_id=post.id, action='like') }}">Like</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Let's assume your `Post` model looks something like this:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    likes = db.relationship('PostLike', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')
```

You'd use:

```
p = Post.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
p.likes.count()
```

Or, you'd use this in your .html file:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if current_user.has_liked_post(post) %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('like_action', post_id=post.id, action='unlike') }}">Unlike</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('like_action', post_id=post.id, action='like') }}">Like</a>
  {% endif %}
  {{ post.likes.count() }} likes
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU THIS WORKS <3

Comment: how would i dislpay the amount of likes

Comment: I edited my answer so you can return the count of the likes for each post.

Comment: Thank you so much man , i have been stuck in this for about 2 days and u effortlessly swooped down and saved me big time. Thanks for the help

Comment: This is great stuff. I am assuming that this should be an ajax call. Maybe someone can add/post that functionality.

Comment: Anyway to implement this without having to reload the entire referring page?

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that the user instance does not have a `likers` relationship properly defined.

I suspect there are several errors here:

1. Your `likers` table should have the foreign key for `liker_id` pointing at the users table, not posts.
2. Your `liked` relationship in the `User` model should be a relationship with the `Post` model (with the `likers` table as secondary) and not be in a relationship with itself (ie the `User` model). 
   Try this for your relationship:

   ```
   liked = db.relationship(
   'Post', secondary="likers",
   primaryjoin="likers.liker_id == users.id",
   secondaryjoin="likers.liked_id == posts.id",
   backref=db.backref('likers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
   ```
3. Your `is_liking()` method seems strange. I would write it as either:

   (if not expecting many liked posts per user) `return post in self.liked`

   (if expecting many liked posts per user) `return db.session.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likers WHERE liked_id = :post_id AND liker_id = :user_id", {'user_id': self.id, 'post_id': post.id}).fetchone()[0] > 0`
4. (not related but possibly incorrect) The order that your User model inherits from `db.Model` and `UserMixin` matters, currently your UserMixin is only used for methods which are not found in db.Model and will not override anything (maybe that's what you want). Ref: Python's [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) (MRO)

Comment: i know have this problem `builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'liker_id'`

Answer (score 0):

Above code works but logout of user maker error because of the "current_user" . So our html file must be like this

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if current_user.has_liked_post(post) %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('like_action', post_id=post.id, action='unlike') }}">Unlike</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('like_action', post_id=post.id, action='like') }}">Like</a>
        {% endif %}
        {{ post.likes.count() }} likes
    {% else %}
        {{ post.likes.count() }} likes
    {% endif %}{% endfor %}
```